# How to get /proc/net/dev data with sysctl function call?

Tags: c, linux, libc

In my app I need network usage statistics (received bytes and packets) for each interface in the system.

I found how to do that in FreeBSD:

```
static int name[] = { CTL_NET, PF_LINK, NETLINK_GENERIC, IFMIB_SYSTEM, IFMIB_IFCOUNT };

sysctl(name, 5, &data, &len, NULL, 0)
```

But that's not working in linux (there is no PF_LINK flag and no if_mib.h in my 4.14 linux kernel). And I'm think that parsing /proc/net/dev is not actually idiomatic way.

Where I can find full hierarchy description of all flags (or just NET flags) to sysctl and their impact on data return?

Comment: Why isn't parsing `/proc/net/dev` the idiomatic way?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html may help

Comment: Thanks @Ctx a lot! getifaddrs returns list of interfaces and type AF_PACKET of each real interface contains both bytes and packets (rx and even tx). It's exactly what I'm looked for.